# RunTimeError: ActionController::RackDelegation in rspec 2.10.1 for rails 3.1.4 application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

In our rails 3.1.4 app, `rspec` is used to test the public method `require_signin` in application controller. Here is the method require_signin:

```
  def require_signin
    if !signed_in?  
      flash.now.alert = "Log in first!"
      redirect_to signin_path
    end
  end
```

Here is the `rspec` code:

```
it "should invoke require_signin for those without login" do
  controller.send(:require_signin)
  controller {should redirect_to signin_path}  
end
```

The above `rspec` generates gigantic multi pages error starting like the below:

```
RuntimeError:←[0m
       ←[31mActionController::RackDelegation#status= delegated to @_response.status=, but @_response is nil: #<ApplicationController:0x3
a67f10 @_routes=nil, @_action_has_layout=true, @_view_context_class=nil, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_reques
t=#<ActionController::TestRequest:0x3a68720 @env={"rack.version"=>[1, 1], "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x34fad60>, ........
```

What could be wrong with the `rspec` code? Thanks so much.

Comment: Add a bounty please. I need this answer too

Answer (score 4):

I came across this errror and realized I was triggering a redirect on the controller by calling a helper method I wanted to test, but I hadn't actually instantiated a test request yet.  Calling `get :index` before calling the expectation got rid of the error.

```
it "redirects if some condition" do
  subject.send(:helper_method)
  get :action # <= Need this before setting expectation below
  response.should redirect_to("/somewhere")
end
```

Comment: Thanks from the future! This just fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check action mechanics, you should use `should_receive` before a `send` call like this

```ruby
it "should redirect to signin_path" do
  controller.should_receive(:redirect_to).with(signin_path)
  controller.send(:require_signin) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be entirely useful, but I came here after getting the same error. I started with a passing test suite, made some changes, and then started getting errors like:

```
RuntimeError:
    ActionController::RackDelegation#status= delegated to @_response.status=, but @_response is nil:
    ...many lines...
```

After taking a closer look at the error, I noticed that it said somewhere:

```
@flashes={:alert=>"You have to confirm your account before continuing."}
```

I had just added the `:confirmable` option in Devise, and realized that all users that I created that I was trying to sign in as were unconfirmed, and as such could not successfully log in. I needed to add `confirmed_at Time.now` to my factory/fixture creation for users. In your example though, it seems like you are trying to test when not logged in, so I'm not sure this is necessarily applicable.